# How to add the single wait for two different element in Selenium [C#]

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have two different form in my application and form input data loading can be done using the predefined template which is available in UI(i.e Input Text Field value will be pre-populated based on the template selection). When the data loading happens, element rendering will not happen and only input field value will be populated. In order to confirm the data loading , I am using the wait as below

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.XPath(Element1_FieldXPath)).GetAttribute("value").Length > 1);
```

At any point of time, either Form1 or Form2 alone will be visible. So, I need to confirm the data loading in either Form1 or Form2. So, I need to write a generic method to handle this situation and I have come across the below solution,

```
public bool IsDataLoadingCompleted()
{
   var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

   try
   {
       wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.XPath(Form1_FieldXPath)).GetAttribute("value").Length > 1);
       return true;
   }
   catch (TimeoutException)
   {
       try
       {
           wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.XPath(Form2_FieldXPath)).GetAttribute("value").Length > 1);
           return true;
       }
       catch (TimeoutException)
       {
           return false;
       }
   }      
}
```

In my solution, the worst case wait time is `120s` when the form2 is visible in UI.  I need to solve the above problem with single wait instead of double wait.

Is there any other way to solve the problem with minimal wait time?

**Sample HTML:**

**Form1 - Field1 HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group field field-string">
    <label class="control-label" for="root_employeeName">Employee name</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="root_employeeName" label="Employee name" placeholder="" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

**Form2 - Field1 HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group field field-string">
    <label class="control-label" for="root_employeeAddress">Employee Address</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="root_employeeAddress" label="Employee Address" placeholder="" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: the answer depends on the locators for these forms. Can you share html code for the forms?

Comment: @theGuy: Sample HTML is added in Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *comma separate* the ***CssSelectors*** to construct a `OR` logic and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR A`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector('#root_employeeName, #root_employeeAddress')));
  ```
- `CSS_SELECTOR B`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("label[for='root_employeeName'], label[for='root_employeeAddress']")));
  ```
- You can find the reference in [Groups of selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#grouping)

**Working Code:**

```
public bool IsDataLoadingCompleted(){

    var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
    try
    {
        wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[label='Form1_Field'],[label='Form1_Field']")).GetAttribute("value").Length > 1);
        return true;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be a nice solution. Only works for css-selectors, or also for xpath, className and linkText?

Comment: The above suggestion is worked out for me. I have edited the answer with working code

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that one form is always displayed and locators have a static `id`

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("input[class='form-control']")))
string elementid = FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[class='form-control']")).GetAttribute("id") // or GetAttribute("label") 
if(elementid=="root_employeeName"){
 // do your action here if name form is displayed
}
else if(elementid=="root_employeeAddress"){
// do you action here if Address form is displayed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this by using tasks run in parallel. The required code would look something like below, where `Task.WaitAny` does the trick.

```
public static bool WaitUntilOneFormLoaded(IWebDriver driver)
{
    var task1 = IsFormLoadedAsync(driver, "//some/xpath1");
    var task2 = IsFormLoadedAsync(driver, "//some/xpath2");
    Task.WaitAny(task1, task2);
    var completedTask = Task.WaitAny(task1, task2);
    switch (completedTask)
    {
        case 0: return task1.Result;
        case 1: return task2.Result;
        default: return false; // Timeout
    }
}

public static Task<bool> IsFormLoadedAsync(IWebDriver driver, string xpath)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            wait.Until(x => driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath)).GetAttribute("value").Length > 1);
            return true;
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This only works when the timeouts are equal (in this case 60 seconds). Imagine what happens when one timeout is set to 30 seconds and the other to 60.